# slimScroll and twitter widget wont work on mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slimscroll

I have example at

```
$(function () {
           $('#scroller').slimScroll({
               height: 600,               
            });
        });
[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xyyoPe)
```

My problem is that i cant get the scroll to work with the mouse wheel and slimscroll in this example. I dont know if the css is the issue or if the whole div setup is wrong.

Comment: slimScroll seems to be working just fine. The div area simply doesn't have enough content (tweets), so the scrollbar takes the whole area. Check this [example](https://codepen.io/pierrebonbon/pen/oaQvpM). I added Lorem Ipsum to your pen, where you had 'Tweets by TwitterDev'.

Comment: ive looked at your example but the mouse wheel still doesn't scroll the content.ive tried chrome and firefox and opera. I can manually use the slimScroll scroll.

Comment: The example I posted above is working just fine with me. [Here](https://gifyu.com/image/TsnD)'s me using the mouse wheel.

Comment: it works with mouse wheel for me if i remove the script tag - the script tag that displays the twitter widget. I have changed the tweet count to 20 and still i cant use the mouse wheel.

Comment: But do tweets show up at all? From what I get, the issue is not with slimScroll, which is working, but with the timeline instead, which is not being displayed, only the tag.